# Putty Crashing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, script, putty

Upon running a `bash script` via `exec` on Windows 7, putty crashes. The putty application closes unexpectedly without any errors that I can see.

How can I figure out why it's crashing?

**EDIT** Running a script inside of putty results in putty crashing.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `-v` flag for a more verbose output, but what is the command that is crashing anyhow?

Comment: `exec <some script>` and `. ./<some script>`

Comment: So it's not actually calling putty that causes it to crash? It might be trying to use some of putty's resources..

Comment: oh. correct, running the script `after` putty is up and running is causing the issue. putty crashes when I try to run the script

Comment: OK, so you open putty to do other things (is it connected, or unconnected, and does this make a difference?) and then run the script and putty crashes?

Comment: After using putty to `ssh` to a server, I run a script that causes putty to crash. I've used putty before on this server for an extended amount of time without any crash before.

Comment: OK, so you actually run the command in putty? Which would mean that you are running the command on the server. Which means you are probably running a script which 1. Kills your login on the server 2. resets the connection 3. resets sshd. Can you post a sanitized version of the script?